# Append span after an word in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have following JS:

```
str_counter.append(config.counter.message).fadeIn();
$('<span />', {
    text: config.counter.countdown
});
```

The config.counter.message says following at the moment: '*Please wait seconds to proceed!*'.

How can I append that span right after specified amount of characters... In this sample that would be:

> 'Please wait' + config.counter.countdown + 'seconds to proceed!'

But since it's configuration I would like to specify an X amount of characters... After that amount span will be appended. Possible or just my bad imagination ?

Comment: `'please wait <span>' + counter + '</span>blah blah blah'`? It's all just text. don't overcomplicate/overengineer/overthink things.

Comment: use a replace function

Comment: I don't see why you're using span. Span does nothing unless coupled with CSS or an ID tag and Javascript functionality. It's better that you just use your variable. You're going about it the wrong way. I'll give you a simple demonstration and you can extrapolate the answer. By the way, I think you got down voted because you didn't phrase your question properly. "Possible or just my bad imagination?" is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this in your html:

```
<span>Please wait <span id="js-counter"></span> seconds to proceed!</span>
```

Then this in your JS:

```
$('#js-counter').html(config.counter.countdown);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was gonna post :P.